# Email activation in Django failing in different browsers

Tags: django, activation

My app has email activation. However, the activation link fails when the user creates an account in one browser and tries to verify the link from another browser. The error message is 'Activation Link is invalid.'

It usually works when the user tries to use activation link in the same browser. However, sometimes it still fails and I still get 'Activation link is invalid.' Basically, I don't know why it's failing with sometimes and not others.

```
try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
    user = None
if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
    .... do something
else:
    return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

Here is where I create the email:

```
def activation_email(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user=request.user
        message = render_to_string('email.html', {
                'user':user,
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
        })
        ....send mail
    else:
        return redirect('somewhere_else')
```

Basically, Django is not able to recognize the user. Not sure why it fails sometimes, I'm guessing it's failing at the if user.is_authenticated statement.

Comment: It does not make sense when it comes to `user.autheticated`. Because its the activation emails for user before the login, and here without login, they can't activate. I suggest to remove `user.is_authenticated` clause from `if` in both views.

Comment: Sorry that was a debug error, it's actually "if user is not None". Still exhibits similar behavior - with breaking for some users

Comment: can you update the question with latest code please?

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: @rudda, I tried to ask it again with more info, maybe your can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939607/trying-to-verify-a-user-with-django-email-confirmation-however-some-users-are