# Trying to verify a user with Django email confirmation, however some user's are getting this error when they try to confirm their email

Tags: django, email, activation

I asked a variant of this question before, but realized I was very unclear. This is my attempt at doing a better job of explaining the issue.

I send a link to a user's email to confirm sign-up after they have registered for the site. However, a small proportion of users are getting the following error when they try to confirm their email.

Error:

```
TypeError/activate/{uidb64}/{token}/
error
'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

I think the problem is that the activate function is not recognizing them. However, not sure how to make this activation link work if I send them back to the login page. Any ideas?

Do I need to add something like 'if not user.is_authenticated:' then send redirect to login? But, how do I come back to activate function? Login is general in my app to all situations.

Activate code:

```
try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
    user = None
if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
    .... do something
else:
    return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

Here is where I create the email:

```
def activation_email(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user=request.user
        message = render_to_string('email.html', {
                'user':user,
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
        })
        ....send mail
    else:
        return redirect('somewhere_else')
```

EDIT>: It's failing when I try to update my model with the email verification info:

```
if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
      object, created = User_Profile.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user,
            ## This is where it fails
            email_validated=True,
        )
```

Comment: Please help someone :), I've been thinking about this for a week.

Comment: can you share the full error stacktrace?

Comment: @ruddra what particularly are you looking for in the stacktrace, there's a lot. I think I added the most relevant part.

Comment: I would prefer if you add it with the line number and at which line of code you are getting the error?

Comment: @ruddra, I added a comment above the line of code. It's the line, 'email_validated = True' and it's under the if statement: 'If not user is None..:.' in the top activation function. My guess is that it cannot find the User model to match it to, since the user is 'AnonymousUser', i.e. Django cannot associate their info with them.

Comment: `object` is a python keyword and shouldn't really be used as a variable name

Comment: @ChidG sorry changed that name for privacy. It's not actually object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach for activating user is wrong here. I don't think you would need to activate users who are authenticated. Because if they are authenticated, it means they are active users, hence they don't need activation.

And regarding the error, when users are activated, you got the user information here:

```
if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):  # <-- in user variable
```

So why not use it in the next section(as per comments):

```
obj, created = User_Profile.objects.get_or_create(
    user=user,  # <-- here
    email_validated=True,
)
```

Comment: I see. That's not the line with the error - it's the following line - email_validated = True.  How do you explain the 'AnonymousUser' is not iterable?

Comment: You said in the comments that `it's under the if statement: 'If not user is None..:.' `,  and there you should get the value of `user` which you got by token validation.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking at the variables, it is pulling the user information for that user. user has the correct user. But why does it only fail sometimes, shouldn't it always fail if this is the issue?

Comment: It still fails when I try to activate the link in a different browser then where I created the account.

Comment: because user is authenticated(user is logged in) in those cases.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to have worked. Will test it some more.